# Error: Could not find or load main class net.corda.explorer.Main while running "java -jar corda-tools-explorer-4.6.jar"

Tags: corda

I have downloaded the corda-tools-explorer-4.6.jar and want to install it on my local machine. While executing the command `java -jar corda-tools-explorer-4.6.jar`, I am getting the below error message.

> Error: Could not find or load main class net.corda.explorer.Main

Please help me to resolve the issue as I haven't got any solution to it.

Comment: Hi @amit-chandra I downloaded it and I can run it without problems. Do you have Java 8 installed in your local machine?

Comment: Yes,Alessandra..I have installed the Java 8 in my machine.
One more question, In order to communicate Node explorer to Corda Node.I have to keep the useSSL flag to FALSE in node.conf file. It is not working with TRUE option.
This has happened with corda earlier version + node explorer.

Is there any solution to it. My Node explorer is in Windows and Corda Node in Linux Machine. The RPC communication is happening through Loadbalancer.I am using AWS for deployment purpose.

Comment: Are you using Corda OS or Corda Enterprise? I just noticed that the jar you are running is only for the latter. If you are using Corda OS, you should download the latest version from here: https://github.com/corda/node-explorer/releases

Answer (score 0):

It looks like based on the comments there's a couple questions here.

For how to run corda:

Generally you're going to want to run your corda projects using gradle to build them. Make sure you include the correct dependencies for each module of the cordapp (remember to double check the build.gradle files of contracts and workflows). For a good example of this check the java cordapp template here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/.

You'll want to make sure you include all the corda dependencies, those look something like this:

```
//Module dependencis
dependencies {
    // Corda dependencies.
    cordaCompile "$corda_core_release_group:corda-core:$corda_core_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies.
    cordapp project(":workflows")
    cordapp project(":contracts")

    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"
}
```

The guide for using the new node explorer is here in the docs (it's open source): https://github.com/corda/node-explorer#downloading-the-node-explorer-binaries

Just download the binary and supply the node connection details.

Good luck and Happy holidays!